# Блокируются JQuery плагины

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Добрый день, подскажите из-за чего плагины могут друг друга блокировать?
То есть если я добавляю 2 плагина: (к примеру)

```html
<script src="templates/plugins/lightbox/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="templates/plugins/chartjs/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

Всегда работает только тот который подключен первым.

Comment: Добавь [mcve] который демонстрирует проблему. Возможно проблема в вызывающем коде, а не библиотеках

Comment: и еще добавь описание что входит в эти файлы и откуда ты их получил. Вполне возможно в каждом из них включена своя версия jQuery